# Is there any way to get unstable features on the compiler versions in stable or beta?

Tags: rust

I'm in a bit of a bind right now. My personal code relies on `rand`, which is currently not compiling on Nightly 1.7, but does work on Beta 1.6 and stable.

However, my work also uses unstable features such as `box` syntax/patterns/raw and `convert` in a way that can't (easily) be refactored out. Is there any way, including by compiling from source, to get Rust 1.6 "as if" it were a nightly? I'm on Windows (10)/MSYS 2 if that complicates things any, such as building the source.

Comment: No; unstable features are strictly disabled on stable and beta builds.

Comment: The easiest way would be to have an old 1.6 around from when your code worked I guess :x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot (trivially) compile any stable version of Rust to use unstable features. Nor can you download the stable version as if it were unstable. However, Rust's downloads has a set of [archives](http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/index.html).

By checking when the most recent release happened:

[image: Date]

I could figure out what day the current Beta was technically a Nightly. Now, presuming there wasn't a major bugfix between the previous Nightly and Beta releases of 1.6, I went to the folder (in this case, December 9, 2015) and downloaded the corresponding Nightly installer from the list.

There are folders going back to 2014-11-07, so if you need a specific version of Rust from the past to compile your code, you can likely find it there.