# Is it possible to compile one specific library with the nightly compiler and link it to a project that is compiled on stable?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am working on a project where a dependency requires a specific nightly feature. I need to use this lib, but I am afraid that if I compile the project with nightly, I could depend on nother libraries that include another unstable feature dependency and I wouldn't be aware of that.

Is it possible to compile the library that I need using nightly (while set the nightly version to version that already merged to the release branch) to some kind of "lib.a" file, and compile the whole project on stable release while linking to "lib.a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

See also:

- [Is there any way to get unstable features on the compiler versions in stable or beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34430429/155423)
- [Is there a way to use unstable modules from Rust stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42048589/155423)